# Iteration from another form - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, iteration

Lately, I've been using this to iterate through some controls in for loops

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    Controls["label" + i].Text = "I am label " + i;
}
```

This sets all controls with the name label, and numbers 1-4 to its corresponding text.
I also found that you can iterate like this for `Properties.Settings.Default["example"], etc`.

Is it possible for to go through the **names** of elements in an array of public static booleans from another form and how would I do this? If this sounds confusing, this is an example of what I'm somewhat looking for;

Form1:

```
public static bool[] T1Cover = new bool[2];
public static bool[] T1Supplied = new bool[2];
public static bool[] T2Cover = new bool[2];
public static bool[] T2Supplied = new bool[2];

T1Cover[0] = false;
T1Cover[1] = true;
T2Cover[0] = false;
T2Cover[1] = false;

T1Supplied[0] = false;
T1Supplied[1] = false;
T2Supplied[0] = true;
T2Supplied[1] = false;
```

Form2:

```
if (Form1.T1Cover[i] || Form1.T1Supplied[i])
   {
    Controls["lblT1P" + a + "A"].Text = Form1.T1Coverers[i];
   }
```

I want to put the above from Form2 into a for loop, where I go through the different array names, and check if an index of the different arrays are true.

An I simply missing something?

Let me know if I can add something for further clarification.

Comment: Do you want to access class member fields using their name in a string? Remember difference between compile-time and run-time...

Comment: As an option you can create a `Model` class containing `Cover`, `Supplied` and `Coverers` properties. Then you can have a `List<List<Model>>` to store values. Then you can simply use a `for` loop to access values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can create a `Model` class containing `Cover`, `Supplied` and `Coverer` properties. Then you can have a `List<List<Model>>` to store values. Then you can simply use a `for` loop to access values.

Here is a sample implementation. You can use this idea for your requirement.

Add this class to the project:

```
public class Model
{
    public bool Cover { get; set; }
    public bool Supplied { get; set; }
    public string Coverers { get; set; }
}
```

Define this member in Form1:

```
public static List<List<Model>> Data = new List<List<Model>>()
{
    new List<Model>()
    { 
        new Model{Cover= false, Supplied= false, Coverers= "A"},
        new Model{Cover= true, Supplied= false, Coverers= "B"},
    },
    new List<Model>()
    { 
        new Model{Cover= false, Supplied= true, Coverers= "C"},
        new Model{Cover= false, Supplied= false, Coverers= "D"},
    },
};
```

Then you can use such loop in Form2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Form1.Data.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Form1.Data[i].Count; j++)
    {
        if (Form1.Data[i][j].Cover || Form1.Data[i][j].Supplied)
            this.Controls[string.Format("lblT{0}P{1}A", i+1, j+1)]
                .Text= Form1.Data[i][j].Coverers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any success with the answer? Any question about it?

Comment: I've been successful with refactoring and am no longer relying on the second form for these results. However, this answer is actually correct in context to my question so I feel you deserve the check. I do have another question regarding this same project but that will be another post, perhaps another day. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for to go through the names of elements in an array of **public static booleans** from another form?

Essentially your question is *"can I access public members in another class?"* - to which the answer is *yes*, because they are `public`.  This operation is made easier because they are also `static`.